# Varying mempool statistics across multiple sources

Tags: mempool

I understand that each node is different and will have a different mempool (and size). But in looking at https://tradeblock.com/bitcoin/ it is showing a mempool size of around 20MB (http://bitcointicker.co/networkstats/ shows similar mempool size of 20MB). But https://blockchain.info/charts/mempool-size is showing a mempool of 103MB (https://jochen-hoenicke.de/queue/#24h showing similar 100+ MB size). Neither site explains how they configure their mempool. tradeblock.com and blockchain.info are referenced from many sources - do you know what can explain this big difference in how they report mempool size? thanks

Answer (score 3):

Nodes have different policy about accepting transactions to mempool. Some nodes accept all transactions, others accept only transactions with a fee greater than 10 satoshi per byte for example.

Nodes have different policy about droping transaction from mempool. Some nodes drop one-day-old transactions, other nodes drop three-days-old transactions.

Nodes have different policy - this is the answer.